# What could be causing my Python drink-water-notifier to not display notifications when launched on startup?

Tags: python, push-notification, python-multithreading, toast

I made a drink-water-notifier in Python. It works when run from the terminal. I used the `playsound` for the music of gulping water and I've used the `win10toast` module for the toast notifier. I also used the `threading` module to thread both operations. It works as expected from the terminal. I made it to run on startup, but only the music is being played, not the notification displayed. Any help?

Here's the code:

```
# TODO: somehow, use a relative path to the .ico and .wav files
import time
from threading import Thread
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from playsound import playsound
import os
import shutil

notification = ToastNotifier()

shell_startup_dir = f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup"
project_dir = "C:/Users/Karmakar's PC/Documents/Arpan Karmakar/Python Programming/projects/drink-water-notifier"

if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(shell_startup_dir, "main.pyw")):
    shutil.copy("main.py", os.path.join(shell_startup_dir, "main.pyw"))


def playsound_fx():
    playsound(os.path.join(project_dir, "water.wav"))


while True:
    Thread(target=playsound_fx).start()
    notification.show_toast(
        title="Drink Water Notifier",
        msg="We should drink about 15.5 cups (3.7 liters) of fluids a day for men. About 11.5 cups (2.7 liters) of fluids a day for women.",
        icon_path=os.path.join(project_dir, "water.ico"),
        duration=10,
    )
    time.sleep(1800)
```

It used to work a few weeks earlier but not now. The current version of python is 3.11.3. I updated the packages and none seems to work (playsound==1.2.2 is the only workable version)

[Task Manager: main.pyw=enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaI9g.png)

PS: Using a new virtual environment doesn't work.

[Working in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zELl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the threaded=True option and also waiting for the threaded notification to finish. This example is from the [project website](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications).

```
toaster.show_toast("Example two",
                   "This notification is in it's own thread!",
                   icon_path=None,
                   duration=5,
                   threaded=True)
# Wait for threaded notification to finish
while toaster.notification_active(): time.sleep(0.1)
```

also run the script in the terminal and check if it is really working without any errors. If yes and you think it's really a problem with the notification and the other thread, provide a minimal example.

Comment: I am actually very new to this thing, could you please provide insights on where to include the threaded=True option? It would really mean a lot. And by the example, umm, the gulping music is played every 1800 seconds. This works but the notification ain't displaying. The notification is displayed only when this script is run from the terminal. Thanks.